# why translator.detect(..).lang gives me exception when I put my code in server whereas it works fine on my local host

Tags: python, google-translate

this is my code portion where I get exception only when I use my code on the server whereas it does not give me an exception when I use it in my localhost, can anyone explain why it behaves differently and how to solve it I really could not understand why. my server machine uses linux and my localhost uses windows.

```
if len(title) > 4:
    try:
        time.sleep(3)
        detection = translator.detect(title[:40]).lang
        # print('detection' , detection)
        if detection != "en":
            print("language detected not english")
            return -4
    except:
        print('inside except checksum')
        return -4
```

title[:40] is a valid string, below is my output

```
Page 0...
inside except checksum
inside except checksum
inside except checksum
inside except checksum
inside except checksum
inside except checksum
inside except checksum
inside except checksum
inside except checksum
inside except checksum
inside except checksum
inside except checksum
inside except checksum
inside except checksum
outdated
inside except checksum
outdated
Page 1...
inside except checksum
inside except checksum
.
.
.
```

Comment: It is hard to say what is throwing the exception because your code destroys the evidence. Change the `except` to `except exception as e` and put `e` in your `print` call.

Comment: Indeed without knowing the exact exception it is really difficult to look for the root cause. Follow BoarGules advice and let us know what exception do you find.